# Convergence of oscillating sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I was trying to do a problem to prepare for my Real Analysis test but i got stuck. The problem states the following:

**Suppose that $x_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $\lim \left((-1)^{n} x_{n}\right)$ exists (Let's suppose $\lim \left((-1)^{n} x_{n}\right) = \alpha$). Show that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges.**

What have i tried so far? My most promissing attempt went like this:

Define $z_{n}:=(-1)^nx_{n}$ We already know that $z_n \xrightarrow{\
} \alpha$. If we can prove that both subsequences $z_{2n}$ and $z_{2n - 1}$ converge to $\alpha$ we'll be done. For that, consider the following subsequence: $$z_{2n} = (-1)^{2n}x_{2n} = x_{2n}$$ We can say that $\lim x_{2n} = \alpha$ because $z_{2n} \xrightarrow{\
} \alpha$ as every subsequence of $z_{n}$ should converge to the same limit $\alpha$.

On the other hand, consider the subsequence: $$z_{2n-1} = (-1)^{2n - 1}x_{2n-1} = -x_{2n - 1}$$ We know that $\lim z_{2n-1} = \lim -x_{2n - 1} = -\lim x_{2n-1} = \alpha$. Therefore, $\lim x_{2n-1} = -\alpha$.

However, i wanted $$\lim x_{2n-1} = \alpha$$ for $\alpha$ bigger than zero in order to finish the proof, because then both odd and even subsequences would be converging to the same limit. Can anyone help me finish this exercise? If this idea cannot be fixed, can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint** prove that $a=0$

Comment: Any suggestions for that task? What did you think of the attempt? I think i could use the fact the $x_{n} \geq 0 $ somewhere to finish the proof

Comment: If $\alpha \neq 0 $ then infinitely many terms will lie outside a nbd of $\alpha$

Comment: After proving $\alpha=0$, argue that for sufficiently large $m,n$ $|x_m|<\epsilon/2,|x_n|<\epsilon/2$.Then use triangle inequality and Cauchy's definition to prove $x_n$ converges.

Comment: Also you can argue that since any subsequence of a convergent sequence has same limit. Your even numbered subsequence and odd numbered subsequence have same limit. Therefore $\alpha = -\alpha$.

Comment: How can i prove that $\alpha = 0$? Furthermore, i want to know if my attempt can be finished somehow

Comment: "Also you can argue that since any subsequence of a convergent sequence has same limit, therefore α=−α" that gives me $\alpha = 0$, right?

Comment: it's a very solid attemt. that's basically what you need to do. use that if $y_n\leq 0$ and $y=\lim y_n$ then $y\leq 0$.

Comment: @Lucas, yes and I have edited my comment.

Comment: I am highly suspicious of my attempt. I am not using the fact that $x_{n} \geq 0$ anywhere

Comment: Is that hypothesis not necessary?

Comment: It is equally valid for $x_n \leq 0$. The main point is $x_n$ doesn't change sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{(-1)^n x_n\}$ is convergent to $x>0$.

$\implies \forall\  \epsilon \ \exists\  N_0\  \forall n>N_0,\ |(-1)^n x_n-x|<\epsilon $
$\implies \forall n>N_0,\ x-\epsilon< (-1)^n x_n<x+\epsilon$.
Choosing $\epsilon$ in such a way that $x-\epsilon>0$ we get that

$\forall n>N_0,\ 0<x-\epsilon< (-1)^n x_n$.

But this is impossible as for odd $m>N_0$, $(-1)^m x_m<0$. $\therefore x\not>0$
Similarly we can prove that $x\not<0$.

Therefore $x = 0$.Therefore $(-1)^nx_n \to 0$

$\implies \forall\  \epsilon \ \exists\  N_1\  \forall m>N_1,\ |(-1)^m x_m|<\epsilon/2,\exists\  N_2\  \forall n>N_2\ |(-1)^n x_n|<\epsilon/2 $.

So for $\forall m,n>\max(N_1,N_2), |(-1)^m x_m|<\epsilon/2, |(-1)^n x_n|<\epsilon/2$

Thus $\forall\  \epsilon \ \exists\  N\  \forall m,n>N,\ |x_m-x_n|<|x_m|+|x_n|<\epsilon $.

Therefore $x_n$ is cauchy. And since Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R$ are convergent, so $x_n$ is convergent.

Now if $x_n \leq 0, Let z_n=-x_n\geq 0$, by above argument $z_n$ converges which in turn implies that $x_n$ converges.

Comment: Why is $\left|(-1)^{m} x_{m}\right|<\epsilon / 2$ true? I think i am missing something

Comment: Same for $x_{n}$

Comment: Because its limit is zero, and $ |x_n|=|(-1)^n x_n|$.

Comment: The limit is zero because of the $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ we previously discussed?

Comment: Regarding the subsequences

Comment: Yeah! Read my answer.

Comment: I am studying your answer right now!! Liked it very much already

Comment: For $x_n \leq 0$ the same proof works right?

Comment: Why do we have $2 \lim (-1)^{n} x_{n}$? I can't figure that 2 multiplying the limit

Comment: @Lucas I changed my answer, This answer is mathematically correct. Previous answer was faulty.